# Find handle of another application's menu (vb .net)

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

I want to make a program that will disable menu items of an appication for parental control using user32's enablewindow function. Using spy++ I can find buttons, controls etc, but I cannot seem to find menus and menu items. How could I find the handle for these so I could disable them when the user trys to click on them?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done (not very sure!) by hooking WH_CALLWNDPROC and handling WM_INITMENUPOPUP or WM_INITMENU messages. Some related discussions can be found here:
[How to find the menu item (if any) which opens a given HMENU when activated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320899/how-to-find-the-menu-item-if-any-which-opens-a-given-hmenu-when-activated) 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/AOTop.aspx